# FB.login spawns new window and cannot get access token

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Been looking around google and StackOverflow, everybody practically have the same advice to do:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
});
```

I have a "share" button on the page, and when click I simply want to do a post on the user's profile and going to use the https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed call to do it. To be able to do that, I need the access_token from facebook, so what I did was:

(after calling FB.init() as well as adding the all.js)

```
 FB.login(function (response) {
    console.log('response.authResponse: ' + response.authResponse);
     if (response.authResponse) {
                var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                console.log('Access Token = ' + access_token);
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
     } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
     }
  }, { scope: 'user_about_me' });
```

What I expect to happen is that it will open a login dialog for the user to facebook, once they login, the dialog closes, it goes back to my page and I get the access token.

But what happens is that it spawns a new browser window to facebook with the login dialog, once the user login, the page proceeds to the user's news feed page and my callback above never gets called. So basically the control is gone and transferred to the new browser window as a normal facebook browsing for the user. When I close that new window though, it execute the "User cancelled login" on my logging.

What am I missing here? All resources simply suggest to call FB.login and that's what I already doing, but I cant seem to get access token for the user.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Full Code and more comments**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
    {
        FB.init(
        {
            appId: '<%= this.ApplicationId %>', // App ID
            channelURL: '<%= this.ChannelFileUrl %>', // Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d)
    {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<%= this.LocaleCode %>/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    } (document));
</script>
```

and then in some js file calling this function (the parameters are not being used yet because haven't really make a post)

```
function postToFacebook(name, caption, description, link, picture, id) {

var accessToken = "";

console.log('fb event subscribe');
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
    console.log('facebook event auth.login');
});

console.log('fb login');

FB.login(function (response) {
        console.log('response.authResponse: ' + response.authResponse);
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            console.log('Access Token = ' + access_token);
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
}, {});
```

}

and sequence of what happen is:

1. printed 'fb event subscribe'
2. printed 'fb login'
3. Code hits FB.login -> opens a new browser window to facebook, after user login the focus stays in that new window, it never goes in to the callback function in the FB.login
4. If I close the window spawned in step 3 above, then the callback function is called and 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.' is printed ('response.authResponse: ' gives null)

Step 1 and 2 are expected, Step 3 is the problem, also the window that open has the url https://www.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for the *[FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)* method it says clearly:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

If you want to stick to a client side flow then the options that are available for that are mentioned in this tutorial: [Client-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).

**tsOverflow edit:**
based on the chat discussion with Nitzan Tomer, found out the issue with my work above:

1. the AppId that was used is registered on facebook to a different Site URL, so even when you are testing locally, need to make sure the AppId has the same domain url
2. the channel.html was missing

Comment: I followed the examples on that link as well - but they also uses FB.login() - so that would still open a new page. Is the only way to hit the oauth url directly and not use the js SDK? When I try to hit the oauth url, I get "Error occured, please try again later" message with no explanation of what went wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hit the oauth url directly"? Also, are you using the deprecated "share button"?

Comment: not using the share button from fb widget, I hit the oauth as in making GET request or JSONP request to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?

Comment: The auth dialog requires the user to see it and interact with it. You need to load it either in a pop-up, a new window/tab or to replace your page with it. In any case the "control" is not yours when the user authenticates using the dialog. There is no way around this, and unless you want to go with the server side auth flow, I suggest that you just accept the pop-up since it's the easiest to implement and users are already used to it.

Comment: I don't mind the pop-up flow ... however my problem is that the pop-up stays open as well as I actually not getting the access_token. As in the original post, it just as if user open a facebook page and start browsing rather than login to facebook with the purpose of getting myself access token

Comment: Oh wow, I'm sorry, I completely misunderstood your situation. Can you please add to your original post the entire js code you are using with the js sdk? That include the loading and initializing of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10277/discussion-between-tsoverflow-and-nitzan-tomer)